# ionic io: push on ios failing to register

Tags: ios, push-notification, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app with Push notification using Ionic IO Beta. On android works everything fine. On ios only in dev mode. When I switch to *dev_push false* I keep getting following from ios emulator (after I accepth the Accept Push Notification dialgo box):

```
Mar 23 02:09:05 em app[31682]: Ionic Push: register
Mar 23 02:09:05 em app[31682]: Push Plugin register called
Mar 23 02:09:05 em app[31682]: PushPlugin.register: setting badge to false
Mar 23 02:09:05 em app[31682]: PushPlugin.register: clear badge is set to 0
Mar 23 02:09:05 em app[31682]: PushPlugin.register: better button setup
Mar 23 02:09:05 em app[31682]: GCM Sender ID (null)
Mar 23 02:09:05 em app[31682]: Using APNS Notification
Mar 23 02:09:05 em app[31682]: Push Plugin register failed
```

When I try to test on a device, I don't even get the dialog box asking about accepting Push notifications. The code is here:

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({
                    'debug': false
    });

    push.register(function(token) {
      $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'registering new token',
            template: token.token
            })

      push.saveToken(token, {'ignore_user': true});

      console.log("updating push token", token.token);

      // ...follows 
});
```

forgot to mention: I have set all the certificates (app, push and profile) into Ionic IO.

Comment: Ever solve this? Having the same exact issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that there were more problems which I needed to fix (I got it working only with xcode building, so far the ionic package still does not want to register my device).

If you are using development certificates you need to create in your ionic.io Settings -> Certificates a certificate with **development** type. So my setup is following:

- I did all the push testing on real device and not in emulator
- **Apple developer console:** (I think that it is important that you generate the profile as last step here)

  - Create app id
  - Create development app certificate and generate *.p12 key
  - Create development push certificate and generate *.p12 key
  - Create development profile (by double clicking on the file, your xcode should open with correct profile)
- **Ionic io settings**

  - Create a development certificate with development type
  - Add generated *.p12 keys a and profile
- **Your ionic code**

  - set dev_push = false

With this all set-up I managed to build *.ipa, targeting 9 IOS (iphone) with working push notifications.

One important thing I learned is that if I try to reinstall (remove and try to install again) the same binary, the application will not work. To get it to work I need to change the version and generate new binary, or install other version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue before, try connnecting your iphone to internet and then rebuild.

If it works, I don't know why it solves the problem.

Comment: why someone remove my answer? i don't mind if it have no upvote, at least they should try it, i got same issue like him , and it is just because i forgot to connecting my iphone to wifi. i think push.save(token) is causing an issue when there is no internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove and add your ios platform, XCode loses all provisioning profile staff and "Automatically manage signing" for you. This makes your existing Provisioning Profile "Invalid". You have to go and regenerate you Provisioning Profile (from IOS Developer Console) again and import to XCode.

In Xcode in Capabilities settings Push Notifications needs to be toggled to ON.

I spent the whole day to figure it out.

Hope it helps.